# Best way to store thousands of numbers in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 250 products and they all come with 52 weeks of history + 52 weeks of forecasts. I need to store these numbers in SQL but can't figure out the best way of doing it. I've only used databases a couple of times before so my knowledge is pretty limited...

I thought about using plain text and read/write with separators. But it felt bad in so many ways and made the entire database kinda useless.

Then I thought of adding 52 columns to the table, but I read it was a bad idea.

So now I'm back to where I began and it's just a table with

```
[ID] [WEEK_NUMBERS] [HISTORY_NUMBERS] [FORECAST_NUMBERS]
```

Is this the best way of doing it?

The ~25000-30000 rows are not a problem?

Comment: 25000-30000  rows is totally not a problem.  You are on the right path!

Comment: Any number of rows below one million is considerd a small database. Storagewise you will have no problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a table something like this:

```
create table ProductHistory (
    ProductHistoryId int identity primary key,
    ProductId int not null references Products(ProductId),
    Type varchar(255) not null,
    Week date not null,    -- storing this as a date is a guess
    Number decimal(38, 10), -- should probably be decimal, but the scale and precision might be overkill,
    constraint chk_ProductHistory_type (type in ('Forecast', 'Actual')
);
```

This is an example.  It is unclear:

- Should each row have a column for Forecast and Actual, or should they be on separate rows?
- How should the `week` be stored?
- What is the right type for `Number`?

But the idea is the same . . . at least one row per product/week combination.

Comment: Alternatively, you could follow industry standards and name the primary key just `ID`

Comment: @Bohemian . . . I *do* not consider that in "industry standard".  You might investigate the purpose and use of the `USING` clause if you think differently.

Comment: I never use `using`, because it's not portable, it takes more characters to type (yes, it does!), and doesn't give any performance benefit. It's right up there with `natural join` in the bad idea list. Thinking *beyond* SQL, if you wire up your DB using a framework like JPA, if you name every ID column differently you end up with perfunctory code to cater for variations in the naming of a field that is from an OO perspective the *same* field with the *same* behaviour (auto increment etc). That is bad design. Naming it the same everywhere means less code, one base class for all tables, etc

Comment: @Bohemian . . . It is a shame you don't use `USING`.  `NATURAL JOIN` is an abomination.  `USING` is eminently practical.  It is also part of the SQL standard and supported by Oracle, MySQL, Postgres (and Postgres-derived databases), Teradata, BigQuery, and probably other databases as well.

Comment: A shame? Hardly. I don't use it mainly because all my ID columns are called `id`, but even if they were redundantly named `tableId`, very often there are non-column conditions in join conditions *or* the reference to the column is ambiguous, so then I would have a mix of `using (tableId)` and `a.id = b.tableId`, which is bad. Besides I can see at a glance what columns are being joined on. I completely don't care about `using`. Its failings are similar to `naturals` failings, which is primarily the absence of table references and therefore brittleness.

Comment: @Bohemian . . .`NATURAL JOIN` lacks *table* references and does not use *explicitly* defined foreign key relationships between tables.  You may not like `USING` because of your naming conventions, but it is not at all similar to `NATURAL JOIN` in its (supposed) shortcomings.

Comment: fair enough, but I also frequently join where there is no FK defined, or even to a PK or even another column at all (just a constant). I consider using a single syntax for all joins a good practice. It's easier to read and maintain, and the plain condition covers all cases; `using` only works for a subset, IMHO actually only a (boring) edge case.